# Compile TypeScript from command line

Tags: typescript

I installed ts -global;
ts config is default, but I want to compile my file with custom config.
It's works when I use command `tsc`
But if I add path `tsc myfile.ts`nothing work.

For example, I change `"target": "esnext",` from default `"target": "es5",`
And it is only work with command `tsc` or `tsc myfile -target esnext`

WHY IT IS NOT WORKING WITH COMMAND `tsc myfile`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tsconfig.json` is *only* used if `tsc` is invoked without any parameters.

You already figured this out, but to use `esnext`, you need to use the `--target` argument or compile your entire project (instead of just 1 file).

This is by design (maybe not good design but who am I to say)

Comment: [Relevant issue on the Typescript issue tracker](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27379)